# Query a specific index value in a multivalue field in Solr

Tags: solr

So I have the following multifields in my Solr docs (just an example).

```
"type": [
    "Single",
    "Series",
    "Other association"
],
"name": [
    "Name associated with first type",
    "Name associated with second type",
    "Name associated with third type"
]
```

I'm to be able to query both fields with:

```
name:"Name associated with third type" AND type:"Series"
```

But I need to query the value of `name` and also match the `type` value in the same array index. So the above example should not hit because *"Name associated with third type"* is third `name` and *"Series"* is second in `type`.

A query that should produce a hit would be this, because both values are in the same array index.

```
name:"Name associated with second type" AND type:"Series"
```

But this matches everything. I hope this was properly explained. I don't even know if this is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not possible to match across two multi-valued fields with the same index. You will need to get all the docs that match and deal with them in the client side.

However, if you will always have the full values for both `type` and `name` then you can alter your schema and make it work like this.

Define a new field called `type_names` which is a multi-valued string field. Modify your indexer to set values in that field like

```
type_names: [Single#Name associated with first type,
             Series#Name associated with second type,
             Other association#Name associated with third type]
```

I am using `#` but you can use any delimiter string that works for you.

(You may want to lower case everything in your index if you want case-insensitive matching and also lower-case your query values.)

Then query this field like:

```
type_names:(Series#Name associated with second type)
```

If it so happens that you know the full value for `type` but only one word in `name` (say `second`), then you can use regex match:

```
type_names:/Series#.*second.*/
```

Comment: I'm assuming you could use a copy field for this, but how could you set up custom indexing logic which concatenated the array indices?